# How can I enable native resolution on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus in my AIR app made using Flash CC 2014?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, ios8, flash-cc

I guess I will at least have to include some new Default-something.png-images, but I have had no luck with the sizes I have tried so far.

I am publishing using AIR 16.0.0.214 to an iPhone 6.

Comment: the release notes mention this problem so no solution until next update. Why nobody read the release notes?

Comment: Oh. Does it? Is this just a problem with AIR 16.0.0.214, or is there no version of the AIR SDK that supports the full resolution on the new iPhones yet?